# Conditional mean of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I have two independent exponential random variable $v$ and $u$ with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. What is the mean of $v$, knowing that $v$ happened before $u$ i.e. $E[v|v<u]$?

Comment: It depends on the full joint distribution of $(v,u).$  If you intend them to be independent, please specify that.

Comment: Yes, they are independent

Comment: We have so many closely related posts that I'm sure you can find several solution methods already explained here: [try this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exponential+independent+expect*).

Answer (score 0):

By the law of iterated expectations,

$$\begin{align}E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}]&=E[E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}|{\bf1}_{v<u}]]\\
&=E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}|{\bf1}_{v<u}=1]P({\bf1}_{v<u}=1)+E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}|{\bf1}_{v<u}=0]P({\bf1}_{v<u}=0)\\
&=E[v|v<u]P(v<u)\\
\implies E[v|v<u]&=\frac{E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}]}{P(v<u)},
\end{align}$$
where $$\begin{align}E[v{\bf1}_{v<u}]&=\int_\Omega v f(u,v)dudv,\\
P(v<u)&=\int_\Omega  f(u,v)dudv,\\
\Omega&:={\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R^2}:u>v\}}.
\end{align}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think it should not be a problem compute the two integrals. Alternatively, can i say that $E[v|v<u]$ is equalt to $E[\min(v,u)]$, thus since the $\min$ is distributed as an exponential r.v. with parameter $\lambda+\mu$ the result is $\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}$?

Comment: Considerations of units of measurement tell us the answer must remain the same when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are scaled by the same positive amount.  Since that's not the case for $1/(\mu+\lambda),$ that cannot be a correct answer.

Comment: @simone123 $E[\min(u,v)]=E[v|v<u]P(v<u)+E[u|u<v]P(u>v)$ so the mean of the min is different than what you want.

Comment: Weird because I have computed the first integral which is $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)^2$ (It should be right since I have checked by computing the integral online for fixed values). Regarding the second one it is a known result and it is $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$, thus the result is $1/(\lambda+\mu)$

Comment: Also if I consider the equation suggested by @Golden_Ratio, with the result I found, the equation is satisfied. I think my answer is correct.